# Pearson's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, quadrature

The problem is (book : ordinary differential equations, Birkhoff, 1969, exercises C.6, p.72):

a) Obtain a recursion relation on the coefficient $a_k$ of power series solutions $\sum a_k x^k$ of Pearson's DE $y' = (D+Ex)y/(A+Bx+Cx^2), A ≠ 0$.

b) What is the radius of convergence of the solution ?

c) Integrate by quadratures, and compare.

For a), i found $a_{k+1} = \frac{a_{k-1}(E-C(k-1))+a_k(D-Bk)}{A(k+1)}, k \geq 2$

For b), first, i wanted to use $\lim \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right|$, but i think it's not a good idea. I tried to define a new sequence $(b_n)$ : $b_k = a_{k+1} - a_k$, but i'm lost...

For c), i have $\int \frac{D+Ex}{A+Bx+Cx^2}dx = \frac{1}{2C} \left( E \ln(A+x(B+Cx)) - \frac{2(BE-2CD)}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}\arctan(\frac{B+2Cx}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}) \right)$, but what can i say ?...

Comment: The solution of a linear DE is defined on the largest interval that has all coefficients continuous. With analytical coefficients, the radius of convergence is the radius of the largest disk in the complex plane that does not contain singularities of the coefficients, here the roots of $A+Bx+Cx^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Regarding the convergence radius we can consider sufficient conditions. Observing the recurrence

$$
a_{k+1}=\frac{E-C(k-1)}{A(k+1)}a_{k-1}+\frac{D-Bk}{A(k+1)}a_k
$$

for big $k$ we have the recurrence

$$
Aa_{k+1}+B a_k+C a_{k-1}=0
$$

This recurrence has as solution

$$
a_k = \left(\frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}\right)^k c_1+ \left(\frac{-B-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}\right)^k c_2
$$